# Using the split in java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to read in two fractions from joptionpane.
I want the user to enter two fractions, each split by a space.
i.e 2/4 3/5 should read 2/4 and 3/5.

This is my code so far

```
String input =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the two fractions you want to add \nFor example (2/4 1/6)");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner (input);
                String stringNumbers = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] rationalNumbers = stringNumbers.split("/");
                int numerator = Integer.parseInt(rationalNumbers[0]);
                int denominator = Integer.parseInt(rationalNumbers[1]);
                String [] rationalNumbers2 = stringNumbers.split(" ");
                int numerator2 = Integer.parseInt(rationalNumbers2[0]);
                int denominator2 = Integer.parseInt(rationalNumbers2[1]);
                Rational rationalNumber1 = new Rational (numerator,denominator);
                Rational rationalNumber2 = new Rational (numerator2,denominator2);
                Rational sumOfRationalNos = rationalNumber1.add(rationalNumber2);
```

I can read in the first fraction fine, but I'm unable to read in the second one.
I know the split doesn't work because there's a space so how would I "skip" the space and move onto the next fraction?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is, you're splitting the input at the the slashes before you're splitting at the space. So, if you gave the input `"2/4 1/6"` you'd actually ending up with the array `{"2", "4 1", "6"}`.

Consider splitting the input at the space first, then splitting the two halves at the slashes.

```
String[] halves = input.split(" ");
String[] first = halves[0].split("/"); // The first fraction
String[] second = halves[1].split("/"); // The second fraction
```